# Update multiple results at once in Django

Tags: django, django-queryset

I want to update budget of Category model in Django.

```
class Category(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    budget = models.DecimalField(default=0.0, decimal_places=2, max_digits=12, help_text="Amount in dollars ($)")
```

I would have a list of new budget like this which is equal to number of data in Category:

```
>>> new_category_budget
[Decimal('2700.000'), Decimal('750.000'), Decimal('1500.000')]
```

I am updating like this:

```
>>> for budget in new_category_budget:
...     Category.objects.filter(user=2).update(budget=budget)
... 
3L
3L
3L
```

But all of these return the same data. What's wrong with my update statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're doing is iterating over your budget values, and updating *all* records with user=2 to each one, overriding the previous value.

The return value of [QuerySet.update](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#update) is the number of updated records. Each time you call update(), you get the result that 3 records were updated.

I don't quite understand what you are actually trying to do, but it might be something like this (untested!):

```
for (budget, category) in zip(new_category_budget, list(Category.objects.filter(user=2)):
  category.budget=budget
  category.save()
```

Of course, this assumes that the number of filtered categories will exactly match the number of budgets in new_category_budget, and also the order of iteration over categories is not obvious. All in all, this seems weird :)

Answer (score 0):

When you call `update` on a `QuerySet`, it will set all items in the `QuerySet` to that value.  See the example [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once).

So through your for loop, you are updating all the `Category` objects with `user=2` to each `budget`.  At the end of the for loop, all the `Category` objects should be have `budget == new_category_budget[-1]` or the last budget item.

If you want different values for each `Category` object, you'll need to call `save` on them individually.